# How do I Iterate through a small set of records and retrieve records that match criteria set in each record

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table `tblCriteria` that contains a small (<20) set of records.  Each record has a field of criteria.

I want SQL to move through these records when requested `tblFilterRun`, filter the main table `tblRecords` (~5000 records) and then insert some key fields from the matching records into another table `tblFilterResults`.

```
tblCriteria (CriteriaID, CriteriaText)
tblFilterRun (FilterRunID, FilterRunDate)
tblFilterResults (FilterResultsID, FilterRunID, RecordID, Ref, CustomerID, SupplierID
tblRecords (RecordID, CustomerID, SupplierID...)
```

Previously I would have created something in Access to iterate through each tblCriteria record, but I would like a purely server solution.  I've heard cursors mentioned (usually at the same time as a profanity), what are my options?

Comment: You should avoid _iteration_ in SQL. You need to think about _sets_ and how to query _sets_ of data.

Answer (score 0):

It's not really clear what you need to do with the records in tblCriteria, but can you created a UDF that would do the work of processing one record? Then you can call it on every record using one query like

```
SELECT *
FROM tblCriteria
CROSS APPLY dbo.udf_yourFunction(parameter1, parameter2, etc)
```